# Flutter : statefull component is not updating inside the statefull screen/page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one reusable text input component which is statefull.I am using this component inside the statefull screen form where I am trying to update my input field but is not working.

My TextInput Component.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextInputField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String label;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final Function onInput;
  final Function validator;
  final value;
  final Function onTap;
  final Function onSaved;
  final readOnly;
  final bool showClearIcon;
  final Function onClearTap;
  final Function setValue;

  TextInputField(
      {@required this.label,
      this.onInput,
      this.validator,
      this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
      this.value,
      this.onTap,
      this.onSaved,
      this.readOnly = false,
      this.showClearIcon = false,
      this.onClearTap,
      this.setValue});

  @override
  _TextInputFieldState createState() => _TextInputFieldState();
}

class _TextInputFieldState extends State<TextInputField> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  String storedValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.text = widget.value;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    storedValue = widget.value.toString();

    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
      child: TextFormField(
        key: Key(widget.label),

        readOnly: widget.readOnly,
        controller: controller,
        onChanged: widget.onInput,
        onTap: widget.onTap,
        onSaved: widget.onSaved,
        validator: widget.validator,
        // initialValue: widget.value ?? '',
        keyboardType: this.widget.keyboardType,
        textInputAction: this.widget.keyboardType == TextInputType.multiline
            ? TextInputAction.newline
            : null,
        maxLines: null,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              const Radius.circular(10.0),
            ),
          ),
          filled: true,
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[800]),
          labelText: this.widget.label,
          fillColor: Colors.white70,
          alignLabelWithHint: true,
          isDense: true,
          suffixIcon: widget.showClearIcon
              ? InkWell(
                  onTap: widget.onClearTap,
                  child: Icon(Icons.close),
                )
              : null,
        ),
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Screen/Form

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:edu_assist/widgets/buttons/form_buttons.dart';
import 'package:edu_assist/widgets/inputs/input_text_field.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class AddBranch extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddBranchState createState() => _AddBranchState();
}

class _AddBranchState extends State<AddBranch> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String mapKey = DotEnv().env['MAP_KEY'];

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  Position position;

  static final CameraPosition _kMumbaiLocation = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(19.04665, 74.8470429),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  Future<void> _getMyLocation() async {
    Position p = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    setState(() {
      position = p;
      _setNewMapLocation(p);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _setNewMapLocation(Position p) async {
    var newPostion = CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(p.latitude, p.longitude),
      zoom: 19.151926040649414,
    );
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(newPostion));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add New Branch'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextInputField(
                    label: 'Branch Name*',
                    value: 'sds',
                    onSaved: (String val) {},
                  ),
                  TextInputField(
                    label: 'Lattitude',
                    value:
                        position == null ? null : position.latitude.toString(),
                    onSaved: (String val) {},
                  ),
                  TextInputField(
                    label: 'Longitude',
                    value:
                        position == null ? null : position.longitude.toString(),
                    onSaved: (String val) {},
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 150,
                    child: GoogleMap(
                      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                      myLocationEnabled: true,
                      initialCameraPosition: _kMumbaiLocation,
                      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                        _controller.complete(controller);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  RaisedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _getMyLocation();
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
                    label: Text("Use My Current Location"),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  FormButtons(
                    onSuccessTap: () {},
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here when I tap on "Use My Current Location" button & want to get the user's current location & show it inside the **latitude** & **longitude** input fields.I am updating the state using the `setState` method to set the `Position` but the state of the input field does not update.
My guess is that it is due the the way I handle the initial value in the  component causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `setState`, the stateful widgets inside the state will call the build method and not the `initState` method. Your issue that you are setting the value of the controller in the `initState` function, for this reason the value is not updating.
The solution for you issue is to pass the `TextEditingController` to the `TextInputField`.

```dart
///Check another time if you really want a stateful widget here
class TextInputField extends StatefulWidget {
  ...
  ...
  TextEditingController controller;
  ...
  ...

}
```

Then you need to change the value of position you set the value of the controller like this

```dart
Future<void> _getMyLocation() async {
    Position p = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

      //you don't need setState to update the textfield, controller will 
      // take care of that
      position = p;
      _postionTextController.text=p;
    

  }
```

Side note: if you are creating your custom textfield widget, don't create the controller inside the widget, instead pass it to the widget among the attributes similar to the way `TextField` and `TextFormField` do

Comment: Thanks @Sami Kanafani. Your suggestion worked.I appreciate your feedback. In my app there are lots of forms with 10-20 input fields that's why I thought of creating the controller inside the component which makes it easy to set the initial value otherwise I will have to create lots of controller. Do you suggest any better way to avoid creating lots of controller?

Comment: Since you are using `TextFormField` you can use the attribute `onChange`, in this way you won't need to create a controller for every text field. In addition to that and just a small reminder, don't forget to dispose the controllers after you override the dispose method of the state